# Microsoft Flow - Push notification containing cell value

Tags: excel, push-notification, push, power-automate

New to Microsoft Flow and just used a basic template for now.

So far I have a table containing all the costs when adding some expenses.

Another cell (example ZZ1) contains the full sum of the expenses.

Is there a way for the notification to push the cell value?
For example: Total is {ZZ1}

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As a first step, please add the code you already tried and describe how it doesnt work for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but I don't have any code as its a current template.